# Is the .catchall used to indicate finally clause in smali for Dalvik byte code?

Tags: java, android, smali

I noticed that when there is `finally` clause in the java code, there is always `.catchall` generated to identify the `finally` block or to inline it using the `.catchall` label, but I haven't found any online information about whether is the case or more explanation, does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, A finally block is one case when a .catchall may be generated. However, it can be used for other things as well. For example, it can also be generated in the case of a synchronized method, to ensure the lock is released.

The catch all handler is documented in the [dex-format](https://s.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) specification. Specifically, in the encoded_catch_handler item that is contained in the code_item.

Also related is the equivalent piece of data in the [classfile specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1546). See the catch_type item, in the exception_table.

Comment: @JesysFreke I wish I could upvote your answer multiple times! The documentation does help me read through the code! Thanks again!

Comment: Link is now https://s.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html or https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be expecting too much.

What you are asking about is (in effect) the code generation patterns of the davlik code generator / translator.  In my experience, people don't write detailed descriptions of what compilers / code generators do under the cover:

- These behaviors don't require specifying.  Indeed a specification is liable to do harm, by over-constraining the implementation.
- Such documentation would be expensive to write and maintain.
- Such documentation would have few readers to justify the expense.

I suggest that you look at the source code for the davlik translator and see what it actually does.  (Try grepping for "catchall" ...)

---

Note that the dex format specification gives you the output "language" and what it means.  That constrains what the davlik translator *could* do, but it won't tell you what the translator is actually going to do in all cases.